# VBA do-while loop between 2 values not working

Tags: excel, while-loop, vba

I have to loop a message if `myValue = 0 or myValue > nbRisk`
When the `myValue > 0 and <= nbRisk` I continue 
for exemple if I put myValue = 5 , it loop again and when I put
 myValue = 10 or 11 .. it doesn't loop
Any ideas ?

this is my code

```
Do While myValue = 0 or myValue > nbRisques
myValue = InputBox (Enter number of risk");
loop 
For i=1 to myValue
```

Comment: What is the value of `nbRisques`? Does it change between runs?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this situation. Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: the value nbRisques changes, but I found that I was setting myValue As string not integer, not it's ok , but still don't understand why string works for numbers up to 10, @MattCremeens thank you

Comment: String comparisons work differently from numeric comparisons.  "2" is greater than "10" for example

Comment: ok, but when I enter a string instead of number I have type mismatch , how can I prohibit client from entrering a string

Comment: @BKChedlia try the workaround code below

Comment: Code and error messages should be included in questions as text, not as images or screenshots.

Comment: I would like to know, when I ask a question, why am I having - 4 in my reputation .. ?

Comment: Asking just to avoid it next time, I want to improve my level ... but thank you everybody for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `myValue` to be a Variant.

Your code can then be changed to

```
Do While myValue = 0 Or myValue > nbrisques
    myValue = InputBox("Enter level of Risk to assess")
    If IsNumeric(myValue) Then
        myValue = CInt(myValue)  ' Using CInt on the assumption that you want an Integer
    Else
        myValue = 0
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following workaround:

```
' define myValue as Long
Dim myValue             As Long

Do While myValue = 0 Or myValue > nbRisques
    On Error GoTo InputBox_Err_Handler
    myValue = InputBox("Enter level of Risk to assess")

InputBox_Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error, only Number format is allowed"
    End If
Loop
```